# Range search for emails connected to TimeTree in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a time-tree in Neo4j following the approach from:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/

Then I created an email:

```
CREATE (e:Email {Sender:"A", Recipient:"C"})
```

afterwards I connected the email to the time-tree:

```
MATCH 
 (y:Year {year:2017})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m:Month {month:2})-[:HAS_DAY]->(d:Day {day:10}),
 (e:Email {Sender:"A",Recipient:"C"}) 
CREATE (e)-[r:SENT_ON]->(Day)
RETURN *
```

I did this for many specific dates and now i want to Match every email which was sent between the 01.01.2017 and the 31.06.2017

How can I query that?

Comment: Minor comment: June only has 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a time tree, the graph's relationships encode some temporal relations, so you can use the `NEXT` relationship.

```
MATCH 
  (:Year {year: 2017})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(:Month {month: 1})-[:HAS_DAY]->(d1:Day {day: 1}),
  (:Year {year: 2017})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(:Month {month: 6})-[:HAS_DAY]->(d2:Day {day: 30}),
  (d1)-[:NEXT*]->(d)-[:NEXT*]->(d2),
  (e)-[r:SENT_ON]->(d)
RETURN e
```

For this specific date range (01.01.2017 and 31.06.2017), the following hack works and is probably quicker than the previous solution:

```
MATCH
  (y:Year {year: 2017})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m:Month)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d:Day),
  (e:Email {Sender:"A", Recipient:"C"}),
  (e)-[r:SENT_ON]->(d)
WHERE 1 <= m.month <= 6
RETURN e
```

For handling dates in general, providing a good solution is more tricky than it sounds. Neo4j does not have a built-in Date/DateTime type yet, so it is typical to store them as epoch timestamps and the [APOC library's utility functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_date_and_time_conversions) to convert them.

If you cannot use APOC for some reason, but need to compare date ranges, a possible workaround is to store dates as numbers in `yyyymmdd` format. In that case, you can get dates between 01.01.2017 and 31.06.2017 using the following approach:

```
WHERE 20170101 <= (10000*y.year + 100*m.month + d.day) <= 20170631
```